# Radio Button Slideshow

Tags: javascript, loops, radio-button

I currently have a slide show for my website and i am trying to loop through each radio button. I tried doing it multiple ways, but nothing seems to work. can somebody help please.

here is my code:

```
/*This function is called when the window is done loading*/
window.onload = function() {

//Each of these buttons should call the Change Image Function, passing a differet parameter.
document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function(){
    changeImage("formbackground1.jpg");
    }

document.getElementById("button2").onclick = function(){
    changeImage("formbackground2.jpg");
    }

document.getElementById("button3").onclick = function(){
        changeImage("background2.jpg");
    }

}

var step=1
function  slideit() {
        document.images.slide.src=eval(document.getElementById("button"+step).onclick)
    if (step < 3){
    step++
}
else{
    step = 1
    setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
}
    slideit();
}



/*This function changes the picture when one of the 3 buttons is pressed*/
function changeImage(source) {

    document.getElementById("myImage").src=source;
}


function popup(){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `setTimeout()` I used `setInterval()` instead.

```
var slideTimer = setInterval(slideIt, 3000);
```

With `setInterval()`, we can call `clearInterval()` on a function in order to stop it from executing. This prevents the slideshow from jumping to the next image immediately after the user clicks on a certain image.

```
document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function(){
    clearInterval(slideTimer);
    slideTimer = setInterval(slideIt, 3000);
    changeImage("background1.jpg");
}

document.getElementById("button2").onclick = function(){
    clearInterval(slideTimer);
    slideTimer = setInterval(slideIt, 3000);
    changeImage("background2.jpg");
}

document.getElementById("button3").onclick = function(){
    clearInterval(slideTimer);
    slideTimer = setInterval(slideIt, 3000);
    changeImage("background3.jpg");

}
```

The `slideIt()` function checks which radio button is currently selected, then selects the next radio button and slideshow image. This check occurs every 3 seconds due to `setInterval(slideIt, 3000)`.

```
function slideIt() {
    if (document.getElementById('button1').checked == true) {
          document.getElementById('button2').click();
          changeImage("background2.jpg");
      }
      else if (document.getElementById('button2').checked == true) {
          document.getElementById('button3').click();
          changeImage("background3.jpg");
      } 
      else if (document.getElementById('button3').checked == true) {
          document.getElementById('button1').click();
          changeImage("background1.jpg");
      }  
      else {
          //do nothing
      }
}
```

live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/kkdaily/oLed4em1/

Comment: Thanks you so much. It worked. I really appreciated it. I could not find it anywhere.